# Why my BLoC doesn't work when I don't supply data?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm building the Flutter app for 2FA authentication, however I don't know why, but when I don't type anything in the form, the dialog doesn't show up. Does anyone know how to fix it?

I want it to work like that: when I don't type anything in the form, it must show an Alert Dialog. If I type everything, the BLoC needs to handle the validation.

[image]

## Code:

### manual_input_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'manual_input_event.dart';
part 'manual_input_state.dart';

class ManualInputBloc extends Bloc<ManualInputEvent, ManualInputState> {
  ManualInputBloc() : super(ManualInputInitial());

  @override
  Stream<ManualInputState> mapEventToState(
    ManualInputEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetFormTextEvent) {
      if (event.secretKey == null &&
          event.issuer == null &&
          event.accountName == null) {
        yield ManualInputError();
      }

      yield ManualInputFinal(
        event.secretKey,
        event.issuer,
        event.accountName,
        event.numberOfDigits,
        event.timeStep,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

### manual_input_event.dart

```
part of 'manual_input_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class ManualInputEvent {
  ManualInputEvent();
}

class GetFormTextEvent extends ManualInputEvent {
  final String secretKey;
  final String issuer;
  final String accountName;
  final String numberOfDigits;
  final String timeStep;

  GetFormTextEvent(
    this.secretKey,
    this.issuer,
    this.accountName,
    this.numberOfDigits,
    this.timeStep,
  );
}
```

### manual_input_state.dart

```
part of 'manual_input_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class ManualInputState {
  ManualInputState();
}

class ManualInputInitial extends ManualInputState {
  ManualInputInitial();
}

class ManualInputError extends ManualInputState {
  ManualInputError();
}

class ManualInputFinal extends ManualInputState {
  final String secretKey;
  final String issuer;
  final String accountName;
  final String numberOfDigits;
  final String timeStep;

  ManualInputFinal(
    this.secretKey,
    this.issuer,
    this.accountName,
    this.numberOfDigits,
    this.timeStep,
  );
}
```

### manual_input_screen.dart

```
import 'package:duckie/blocs/manual_input/manual_input_bloc.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/custom_text_field.dart';
import 'package:duckie/shared/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ManualInputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ManualInputScreenState createState() => _ManualInputScreenState();
}

class _ManualInputScreenState extends State<ManualInputScreen> {
  String secretKey;
  String issuer;
  String accountName;
  String numberOfDigits;
  String timeStep;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'manual-input',
          style: TextStyles.appBarText,
        ).tr(),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<ManualInputBloc>(context).add(
                GetFormTextEvent(
                    secretKey, issuer, accountName, numberOfDigits, timeStep),
              );

              BlocBuilder<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is ManualInputError) {
                    showIosAlertDialog(context);
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              );
            },
            child: Text('add').tr(),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'secret-key'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  secretKey = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'issuer'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                issuer = value;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            CustomTextField(
              labelText: 'account-name'.tr(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  accountName = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            ListBody(
              children: [
                Text('number-of-digits').tr(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                  groupValue: '6',
                  children: {
                    '6': Text('6'),
                    '8': Text('8'),
                  },
                  onValueChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      numberOfDigits = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            ListBody(
              children: [
                Text('time-step').tr(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                  groupValue: '30',
                  children: {
                    '30': Text('30'),
                    '60': Text('60'),
                  },
                  onValueChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      timeStep = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showIosAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('manual-input-error-title').tr(),
        content: Text('manual-input-error-content').tr(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (event is GetFormTextEvent) {
      if (event.secretKey == null &&
          event.issuer == null &&
          event.accountName == null) {
        yield ManualInputError();
      }
```

Here instead of && you should use || you only yield the error if all of the fields are null so use:

```
 if (event is GetFormTextEvent) {
      if (event.secretKey == null ||
          event.issuer == null ||
          event.accountName == null) {
        yield ManualInputError();
      }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about OR logic operators. Thanks a lot. I will check it out in 15 minutes and then let you know.

Comment: Okay, I checked the code and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I would add some print statements to see which parts gets invoked and which does not for example

`
if (event is GetFormTextEvent) {
print("checkpoint1);
      if (event.secretKey == null &&
          event.issuer == null &&
          event.accountName == null) {
       print("checkpoint2");
        yield ManualInputError();
      }
`

Answer (score 0):

```
        class MyMainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return BlocProvider(
             create: (context) => ManualInputBloc(),
                child: ManualInputScreen(),
           );
         }
        }


and in ManualInputScreen's action

         actions: [
          BlocListener<ManualInputBloc, ManualInputState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is ManualInputError) {
                showIosAlertDialog(context);
              }
            },
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                BlocProvider.of<ManualInputBloc>(context).add(
                  GetFormTextEvent(
                      secretKey, issuer, accountName, numberOfDigits, timeStep),
                );
              },
              child: Text('add'),
            ),
          )
        ],
```

Comment: Why? Can you explain why BlocListener is better?

Comment: Bloc builder returns a widget and you are not returning anything (null) that's why

Comment: Thanks, i used the answer above, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For validating for emptiness a String try to use more robust statement:

```
value?.trim()?.isEmpty ?? true;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out.